# Change default plastique widget style on QListWidgetItem CheckState(toggled on) as right tick instead cross tick

Tags: qt, qt4, qlistwidgetitem

I'm using Qt 4.4 on Redhat linux.

I added checkBoxes in QListWidget using QListWidgetItem as follows,

```
lstObjListGroup1 = new QListWidget( wgtGroup );
{//loop 
...
QListWidgetItem *itemChkList = new QListWidgetItem( itValue, lstObjListGroup1 );
itemChkList->setFlags (itemChkList->flags () | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable ); 
itemChkList->setCheckState (Qt::Unchecked); //initialize check state
}
```

when I run it, on item selection it shows **cross tick**, but I have to show it as **right tick** on item CheckState.

[image]

How can I change this widget style selection state?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

solved this problem using function QWidget::setStyle() and widget style as "Windows".

[image]

Easiest way i found is by creating a subclass of QListWidget.

```
//header file : echklistwidget.h

#include <qlistwidget.h>
#include <QWidget>

class EChkListWidget : public QListWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        EChkListWidget( QWidget *parent=0);
};
```

```
//source file : echklistwidget.cpp

#include "echklistwidget.h"

#include <qwidget.h>
#include <qstylefactory.h>

class QStyle;

EChkListWidget :: EChkListWidget(QWidget* parent) : QListWidget(parent)
{
    //setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Fusion"));
    setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Windows"));
}
```

```
//using object of subclass EChkListWidget
EChkListWidget *lstObjListGroup1;
lstObjListGroup1 = new EChkListWidget( wgtGroup );
{//loop 
...
QListWidgetItem *itemChkList = new QListWidgetItem( itValue, lstObjListGroup1 );
itemChkList->setFlags (itemChkList->flags () | Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable ); 
itemChkList->setCheckState (Qt::Unchecked); //initialize check state
}
```